# Selective Text Replacement in Latex

Tags: macros

I would like to ask how can I replace selective text in Latex? I am aware of Find and Replace option, but I am looking for a possible way to do as following;

Suppose in the following text I have used a dummy command `\replaceMe{text need to be replaced}` to replace the words "subject" and "author". Please note that the word "subject" also occurs in the second sentence but I did not select it as a text to be replaced.

So, instead of manually using Find and Replace option for each word, is there a possible way of pre-defining the text that is needed to be replaced and then compiling the Latex code to replace at the place(s) mentioned for that particular word each time when I compile?

```latex
% pre-defining the text(s) that is needed to be replaced
\replaceMe1{topic}
\replaceMe2{writer}

% actual text (copied from internet)

Essay are short pieces of writing with a focus on a single \replaceMe1{subject}. It starts with the introduction of the subject, followed by a middle or body in which the \replaceMe2{author} gives his argument as per his understanding of the \replaceMe1{subject} followed by a conclusion paragraph that summarises the findings of the essay.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a new command like

```
\newcommand{\authorname}{Charles Darwin}
```

Then put `\authorname{}` where you want your substitution. When you need a new author throughout, update only the \newcommand entry in the preamble.

The command text, like `\authorname`, can be a slash followed by any string, so long as it is not one that is already defined by LaTeX. So, choose something creative.

The function of the brackets after the string, when the command is used, is just to make sure that a space after the substitution isn’t swallowed up.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Any suggestion for other words except author name?

Comment: Updated to clarify. Does that help?

Comment: Works perfectly!!! Thank you for the clarification